Как добавить фильтр в Datatables если в ячейке кнопка?
Имею таблицу в которой последней колонкой идёт действие с кнопкой по условию:
....
{ data: 'actionBtn' ,
  render: function ( data, type, row ) {
r ='';
if ( row.active == 1 ){
   r = r + '<button class="btn btn-info" value="1" onclick="sendCheck('+row.id+',this,2);return false;"><small>Активировать!</small></button>'; 
}
return r; 
}

Все остальные столбцы я фильтрую с помощью данной конструкции:
       initComplete: function () {            
            this.api()
                .columns([7,9,11,12])
                .every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    // Create select element and listener
                    var select = $('<select class="w-100"><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.header(1)))
                        .on('change', function () {                            
                            column
                                .search($(this).val(), {exact: true})
                                .draw();
                        });
                    // Add list of options
                    console.log(column.data()[12])
                    column
                        .data()
                        .unique()
                        .sort()
                        .each(function (d, j) {                                                       
                            select.append(
                                '<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>'
                            );
                        });
                });
        }

Но последний столбец не доступен для фильтрации, так как там кнопка и нет текста. Как мне выбрать/отфильтровать строки в которых есть кнопка?

Как вариант, добавить к кнопке не отображаемый элемент, по значению которого делать фильтрацию <span style="display: none;">IsActive</span>

Мой коллега сказал, что возможно тут нужно будет прибегнуть к поиску по ортогональным данным
